# how to print from android device when printer and mobile on same network(WI-FI) in android?

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi, network-printers, android-print-framework

I want to print a layout from wifi printer i'm using blow code to print a view but its not working

```
 screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), 
   v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       // screenshot=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(screenshot, width,height, 
       true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
        v.draw(canvas);
        doPhotoPrint(screenshot);
```

//doprintmethod

```
  private void doPhotoPrint( Bitmap bitmap) {
  PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(PrintActivity.this);
   photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
   photoPrinter.printBitmap("Print", bitmap);
   }
```